# Powershell Active Directory get all users from my AD groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I try since a while to create a csv file which contain:
"Group Name","SamAccountName"

Where GroupName is the name of the Group abd SamAccountName is the name of the user which is part of the Group.

I try this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName,memberof | % {
 $Name = $_.DisplayName
 $_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select @{N="User";E={$Name}},Name
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -delimiter "," "All_Users_With_All_Their_Groups.csv"
```

However it doesn't work like I want.

I try to google many example but it's not pretty simple I think as I don't find some relevant example.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I can make it using Quest cmdlet however I would like to use native powershell cmdlet: Get-QADGroup -sizeLimit 0 | select @{name="Group";expression={$_.name}} -expand members | select Group,@{n='User';e={ (Get-QADObject $_).NTAccountName}} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -delimiter "," "../List_Of_All_Groups_With_Users.csv"

Answer (score 0):

This should do your work:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory ;
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*Your Group Name*"} -Properties Description,info | Select Name,samaccountname | Export-Csv D:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
Get-ADGroupMember YourGroupName # to list members ;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I want to export all groupe with their user in one query to have a csv report.

Answer (score 0):

I've created two ways, dunno which one You wanted

```
get-aduser -Filter * -Properties memberof |
%{[pscustomobject]`
@{'Groups Names'=$(($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup).name -join "," );
User=$($_.samaccountname)}}|
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ',' "output.csv"


Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties members | 
%{[pscustomobject]@{'Group'=$($_.name);
'Members'=$(($_.members | Get-ADUser).samaccountname -join ",")}} | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ',' "output.csv"
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your comment, however your command doesn't work for me I've lot of error like this one: `$.name : The term '$.name' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At Query.ps1:49 char:75
+ Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties members | %{[pscustomobject]@{'Group'=$($.name ...
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($.name:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: There is a typo, replace $. With $_. Sorry :) i will fix it today, sorry